# reverse order of projects in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a list of latest projects displaying on the home page of my wordpress site. I can see the section that calls for the projects, but not sure where I can reverse the order.

I know this works for posts.

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . "&order=ASC"); ?>
```

but don't know where to add it. This is the code that calls the projects:

```
   $wpGrade_Options->get('homepage_portfolio_limit') ? $projects_nr = $wpGrade_Options->get('homepage_portfolio_limit') : $projects_nr = 3;

            wpgrade_display_portfolio( $projects_nr, true, true); ?>
```

Comment: wpGrade is a plugin or theme?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using plugin or a theme.

You need to find this function in the plugin/theme files: `wpgrade_display_portfolio`

From command line you would simply do:

```
grep -ir "wpgrade_display_portfolio" wordpress/dir
```

Inside that function there is either a direct call to DB, or if writer of that script was wise built in wp `get_posts`, `WP_POSTS`, or `query_posts` functions.

IF you find any of these wordpress native functions than you can easily reverse order by adding:

```
'order' => 'DESC',
```

If there is a mysql query, then I will have to see it first to give you meaningful answer. I also need to see DB and how you actually would like to order things.